# make animation hover like transition hover

Tags: css, css-animations

i want to change color gray to green then aqua when my element is hover 
and when mouse go out of element:

if my element is green go to gray
if my elemnt is aqua go to green then gray
More accurate i want to make transtion but for 3 colors
when we use transtion for change 2 colors 
the result is great becuase when mouse go out of element, color change Gradually to first value like gray
but in animation when mouse go out of element color very fast change to gray
What is the solution??

this is my code but not working.

```css
@keyframes test {
  0% {
    background: gray;
  }
  50% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: aqua;
  }
}
@keyframes test1 {
  0% {
    background: aqua;
  }
  50% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: gray;
  }
}
.one {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: gray;
  animation: test1 2s;
}
.one:hover {
  animation: test 2s alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
```

Comment: Would you mind using an extra element? So you can let the outer element go from grey to green and the inner element from green to blue?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `:before` pseudo element to cover the background. If you set the element's opacity to 0 as default and to 1 on `:hover` you can use the `transition-delay` to make the second transition appear when the first is done. By overriding the `transition-delay` on the `:hover` you can make sure the "mouseleave" also works properly.

Like this (tested in FireFox only):

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: background-color 1s linear 1s;
}
.one:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.one:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.one:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
```

Comment: tnx for answer its very Intelligently solution

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background to a gradient and animate the gradient position

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 90000px 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, gray, green, aqua);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  transition: background-position 2s;
}
.test:hover {
  background-position: 100% 0%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```